# jQuery JSON I continue to get [object Object] as a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was updating the script for my site to allow for API changes from [v1](https://steamgaug.es/api) to [v2](https://steamgaug.es/api/v2) the changes being

---

V1

```
"ISteamClient": 0,
etc..
```

V2

```
"ISteamClient": {
        "online": 1
    },
etc..
```

---

But now when I write what val is for each of the parts I get `[object Object]` in return, so I found a [guide](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/how-to-read-and-parse-json-using-jquery.html) in which I call `val['online']` but I still get `[object Object]`. I haven't done much work with JSON, just simple first layer JSON (like V1)

```
function loadup() {
    $.getJSON("https://steamgaug.es/api/v2", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        var ISteamClient = 2,
            ISteamCommunity = 2,
            ISteamGameCoorindator_440 = 2,
            ISteamUser = 2,
            IEconItems_440 = 2;
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (key === "ISteamClient") {
                ISteamClient = val['online'];
                console.log(key + " = " + val);
            } 
            else if (key === "SteamCommunity") {
                ISteamCommunity = val['online'];
                console.log(key + " = " + val);
            } 
            else if (key === "ISteamGameCoorindator_440") {
                ISteamGameCoorindator_440 = val['online'];
                console.log(key + " = " + val);
            } 
            else if (key === "ISteamUser") {
                ISteamUser = val['online'];
                console.log(key + " = " + val);
            } 
            else if (key === "IEconItems_440") {
                IEconItems_440 = val['online'];
                console.log(key + " = " + val);
            }
        });
        //Sort and group data
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you still get `[object Object]`? hare: `console.log(key + " = " + val);`?

Comment: *"but I still get [object Object]"* well, accessing `val['online']` does not magically change `val`. `val` is still an object, so it will print `[object Object]` if you convert it to a string. Tip: Pass multiple arguments to `console.log` instead: `console.log(key, '=', val)`.

Comment: *facepalm* I wasn't getting a correct outpurt because `ISteamGameCoorindator_440` was changed to `ISteamGameCoorindator` and I didn't look at `console.log`. Thank you for putting up with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging `val`, which is an object.

I think you want to log `val.online`